# IndexOutOfBounds Error in Zeppelin

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have an issue in Zeppelin that when i try to perform an SQL operation on a temptable (of dataframe) that i've created i always get an IndexOutOfBounds error.

Here's my code:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.net.URL
import java.nio.charset.Charset
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
//import sqlContext._

val realdata = sc.textFile("/root/application.txt")

case class testClass(date: String, time: String, level: String, unknown1: String, unknownConsumer: String, unknownConsumer2: String, vloer: String, tegel: String, msg: String, sensor1: String, sensor2: String, sensor3: String, sensor4: String, sensor5: String, sensor6: String, sensor7: String, sensor8: String, batchsize: String, troepje1: String, troepje2: String)

val mapData = realdata
.filter(line => line.contains("data") && line.contains("INFO"))
.map(s => s.split(" ").toList)
.map(
s => testClass(s(0),
s(1).split(",")(0),
s(1).split(",")(1),
s(3),
s(4),
s(5),
s(6),
s(7),
s(8),
s(15),
s(16),
s(17),
s(18),
s(19),
s(20),
s(21),
s(22),
"",
"",
""
)
).toDF
//mapData.count()
//mapData.printSchema()
mapData.registerTempTable("temp_carefloor")
```

And then in the next notebook i try something simple like:

```
%sql
select * from temp_carefloor limit 10
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 18
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:65)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:84)
    at $line128330188484.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$3.apply(<console>:84)
    at $line128330188484.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$3.apply(<console>:72)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Now i'm sure it has something to do with the way my data is outputted.
But i just can't figure out what i'm doing wrong and i'm really hitting my head here. Really hoping somebody can help me out.

EDIT:
Here's an excerpt of usefull data i'm trying to extract.

```
2016-03-10 07:18:58,985 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] n.t.f.c.FloorUpdateController [FloorUpdateController.java:67] Floor 12FR received update from tile: 12G0, data = [false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false]
2016-03-10 07:18:58,992 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] n.t.f.c.FloorUpdateController [FloorUpdateController.java:67] Floor 12FR received update from tile: 12G0, data = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
2016-03-10 07:18:59,907 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] n.t.f.c.FloorUpdateController [FloorUpdateController.java:67] Floor 12FR received update from tile: 12G0, data = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
2016-03-10 07:19:10,418 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-9] n.t.f.c.FloorUpdateController [FloorUpdateController.java:67] Floor 12FR received update from tile: 12G0, data = [true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

You can see the full flat file here: http://upload.grecom.nl/uploads/jeffrey/application.txt

Comment: there is certainly a problem in you data, can you please provide a sample so that we can take a look

Comment: I've edited my question so you can see the data and the full flat file. Thanks for that.

Comment: first thing I've noticed is when you split your line by `"  "` you'll end up with the fields like `tile:` and `=` that's because they are surrounded with spaces, I think this a problem for you?

Comment: Yeah that might actually be a problem. I had not even taken those into account and it may be why i'm getting an outofbounds error ? Do you have a suggestion on how to better split the data ? The most important bits are the date, tiles and the boolean values.

Answer (score 2):

So as we've discussed in the comments the problem is in the data splitting, you can't split the data with `" "`.

One solution is to split the data using a regex like this `" data = |tile: |[|]| |,"`

You must include all separators in the regex (even the substrings that you don't want them to be in the extracted fields like I did with `" data = "`)

Hope this helps you. Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to try and rewrite it

Comment: @Jdeboer just update the answer when you get the right expression and make the answer as correct

Comment: I'll definetly do that. I'm just struggling with finding the right regular expression right now.